# Source of Entry in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, connectivity, authentication

I want to make a small web app using Postgres as database.

Is there a way to accept database access *if and only if* the SQL command is coming from my app, blocking any other access to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to accept database access if and only if the SQL command is coming from my app, blocking any other access to the database?

No.

Postgres doesn't care which *application* the query came from.

It does, however, care a great deal about the *machine* from which the query was issued and under which *account*.

The first is managed by Host-Based Authentication (HBA), by adding entries into pg_hba.conf.  As long as your application *server* is configured in there, it stands a chance of getting in.  For example:

```
#     Database Account   Address         Auth  (Comment)
host  db1      app_user  11.22.33.44/32  md5   # server44
```

Then, your application will need a database account with which to connect.

Create a Postgres "User" (a.k.a. "login Role") for your application to use and *only* use those credentials within your application.  Use a separate Role to grant privileges on database objects (e.g. tables) and grant that Role to your application User:

```
create table table1 ... ; 

# Application permissions 
create app_role ; 
grant select, insert, update, delete on table1 to app_role ; 

# Developer permissions 
create dev_role ; 
grant select on table1 to dev_role ; 

# Application account 
create user app_user with password '...' valid until 'infinity' ; 
grant app_role to app_user ; 

# A Developer account 
create user fred with password '...' ; 
grant dev_role to fred ;
```

Of course, fred's Development machine will *also* have to appear in pg_hba.conf!